# Jupyter script with images for standalone

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

New to python created a very simple script but seem to be running into issues with images.
I want to take this script and create a standalone.
However when I did it originally without tkinter or imagetk the file would open and close immediately so I tried this.

You can see the error messages I get below the code.

```
> <sub>`import tkinter as tk from PIL import Image, ImageTk
> 
> while True:
>     name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
> 
>     print(f'\nNice to meet you {name}')
> 
>     age = input("\nHow old are you? ")
>     age = int(age)
>     if age >= 40:
>         # Open the "old" image
>         image = Image.open(r'old.jpg')
>     else:
>         # Open the "young" image
>         image = Image.open(r'young.jpg')
> 
>     # Convert the image to a PhotoImage object
>     photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
> 
>     # Create a Tkinter window
>     root = tk.Tk()
> 
>     # Create a label and set the image as its background
>     label = tk.Label(root, image=photo_image)
>     label.pack()
> 
>     # Run the Tkinter event loop
>     root.mainloop()
>     
>     exit_prompt = input("\nEnter 'exit' to close the script, or press Enter to continue: ")
>     if exit_prompt == "exit":
>         break
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9860\2051054611.py in <module>
     17 
     18     # Convert the image to a PhotoImage object
---> 19     photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
     20 
     21     # Create a Tkinter window

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py in __init__(self, image, size, **kw)
    138         self.__mode = mode
    139         self.__size = size
--> 140         self.__photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(**kw)
    141         self.tk = self.__photo.tk
    142         if image:

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   4062         Valid resource names: data, format, file, gamma, height, palette,
   4063         width."""
-> 4064         Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
   4065 
   4066     def blank(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in __init__(self, imgtype, name, cnf, master, **kw)
   3995         self.name = None
   3996         if not master:
-> 3997             master = _get_default_root('create image')
   3998         self.tk = getattr(master, 'tk', master)
   3999         if not name:

~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in _get_default_root(what)
    295     if not _default_root:
    296         if what:
--> 297             raise RuntimeError(f"Too early to {what}: no default root window")
    298         root = Tk()
    299         assert _default_root is root

RuntimeError: Too early to create image: no defa
```

ult root window`

Comment: Can you please add syntax highlighting to your code blocks? You can see [/editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to do so.

Comment: Try now and see if thats better

Comment: Nope! It's worse now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need to call `image.show()` after `image` is opened if you want to show it.

```py
from PIL import Image

while True:
    name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")

    print(f'\nNice to meet you {name}')

    age = input("\nHow old are you? ")
    age = int(age)
    if age >= 40:
        # Open the "old" image
        image = Image.open(r'old.jpg')
    else:
        # Open the "young" image
        image = Image.open(r'young.jpg')
    image.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once that issue was fixed I was getting the following error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11772\4142766009.py in 
> 26
> 27     # Create a label and set the image as its background
> ---> 28     label = tk.Label(root, image=photo_image)
> 29     label.image = photo_image  # Keep a reference to the PhotoImage object
> 30     label.pack()
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py in **init**(self, master, cnf,
> **kw)    3146     3147         """
> -> 3148         Widget.**init**(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)    3149     3150
>
> ~\anaconda3\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py in **init**(self, master,
> widgetName, cnf, kw, extra)    2570         for k, v in classes:
> 2571             del cnf[k]
> -> 2572         self.tk.call(    2573             (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))    2574         for k, v in
> classes:
>
> TclError: image "pyimage28" doesn't exist

I tried fixing it by storing the image:

> import tkinter as tk from tkinter import PhotoImage from PIL import
> Image, ImageTk
>
> while True:
> name = input("\nWhat is your name? ")
> print(f'\nNice to meet you {name}')
>
> ```
> age = input("\nHow old are you? ")
> age = int(age)
> if age >= 40:
>     # Open the "old" image
>     image = Image.open(r'old.jpg')
> else:
>     # Open the "young" image
>     image = Image.open(r'young.jpg')
>
> # Convert the image to a PhotoImage object
> photo_image = PhotoImage(image)
>
> # Create a Tkinter window
> root = tk.Tk()
>
> # Create a label and set the image as its background
> label = tk.Label(root, image=photo_image)
> label.image = photo_image  # Keep a reference to the PhotoImage object
> label.pack()
>
> # Run the Tkinter event loop
> root.mainloop()
>
> exit_prompt = input("\nEnter 'exit' to close the script, or press Enter to continue: ")
> if exit_prompt == "exit":
>     break
> ```

Comment: Problem solved. Thanks for anyone who helped